# Make overlapping div "not clickable" so that content below can be accessed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, event-listener

I am using a JPG overlay with a reduced opacity for an effect, however I want it as an effect only and make the content below that div clickable. Is that possible, thanks :)))

Thanks for your comments everyone. I guess I'll have to think of something else because the JPEG covers the whole page :)

Comment: I think the correct term is hit-testing; and that it's generally impossible on the webs.

Comment: Fastest way I can think of to do this: put your content in a wrapper, make THAT slightly transparent, and put the JPG behind it.

Comment: That's pretty smart Doug, thanks :)

Comment: Hey @pufAmuf, you should come back to this question and accept Andy's answer because this is now possible with CSS and the answer you have currently accepted is no longer the best way.

Comment: Hi @Keavon , I have done so now. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @pufAmuf oh the question is so old I  realized after answering :-D

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Well there is `pointer-events:none;` but only <strike>few browsers</strike> modern browsers (and IE11) support it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: you can check [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events) for browser support

Comment: All modern browsers now support this.

Comment: Note: You can use `pointer-events: auto` to make the element clickable again.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, its possible

Use `pointer-events: none` along with conditional statements of CSS for IE11 (as it does not work in IE10 or below), you can get a cross browser compatible solution to achieve this.

Using `AlphaImageLoader`, you can even put transparent `.PNG/.GIF`s in the overlay `div` and have clicks propagate through to elements lying bellow.

CSS:

```
pointer-events: none;
background: url('your_transparent.png');
```

IE11 conditional:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='your_transparent.png', sizingMethod='scale');
background: none !important;
```

Here is a [basic example page](http://www.searchlawrence.com/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements.html) with all the code.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. The overlaying element will always intercept the click. One possible workaround is to bind a `click` event to the overlaying element, and then get the current mouse position & compare that to the position of the element underneath in order to determine whether or not that element should register a click. But chances are there is a much better way of accomplishing this. Without seeing your code, however, I have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 1):

one simple trick i have found, althoug not very w3c, is to encapsulate the div into a span and use that span class to make the overlay.
That way the whole thing will be clickable , and the div will behave like a div