# Iframe video controls not clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

i am using that example : https://codepen.io/cyborgspaceviking/pen/BdWagp#code-area
but beside using gif files i am using videos and loading them into iframe.
But video controls not clickable.

This is my replacing html with img tag:

```
  <div class="resp-container">
            <iframe class="resp-iframe video" id="gif_tv_video" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"
              allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" src=""></iframe>
          </div>
```

[image: This is output image]
This is my codepen version link: https://codepen.io/affan-sheikh/pen/MWKggOe

Comment: from the preview you've posted, it looks like the img is above the iframe. Are you sure you are actually clicking the iframe and not the image above?

Answer (score 0):

from the preview you've posted, it looks like the img is above the iframe.
Try adding `pointer-events:none;` to every element above to make it not-clickable.

[Check here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700051/make-overlapping-div-not-clickable-so-that-content-below-can-be-accessed)

Comment: I need video controls to be clickable.

Comment: open dev tools, check what elements are above it and add `pointer-events:none;` to the css style of each of them.

Comment: i tried it but no result. but when i move iframe and its container code outside its parent div controls are working.

Comment: can you post a codepen of your code? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: sure.. this is my code pen link: https://codepen.io/affan-sheikh/pen/MWKggOe

Answer (score 0):

It seems overlays are overlapping, try the following:

```
    .gif-tv .viewport .pixels, 
    .gif-tv .viewport .meta-left, 
    .gif-tv .viewport .meta-right {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Comment: Could you also add explanation why this would work?

Comment: You need to remove the `resp-container` wrapper or apply `.video` styles to it.

Comment: `.resp-container {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}`

Comment: i remove .resp-container div and apply my video class to iframe also use your above code but no result.